# How can I disable subtitles by default on VLC for android?

Tags: video, vlc

I went to options > subtitles > and unchecked "auto load subtitles". Still every time I load a video it auto loads the subtitles?

Comment: Just to make sure, are the videos soft-subbed (subtitles are extras on the video and can be toggled on-off) or hard-subbed (subtitles are added directly to the video and cannot be turned off)? Have you tried playing the video with other players and see if they behave the same?

Comment: That setting you mention is as far as I know for loading external subtitles from a separate file. Most subtitles are however embedded into the MP4/MKV or what ever video container is used.

Comment: The videos are not hard subbed. I can turn them off in vlc once the video starts. They are embedded in the mlv container.

Comment: Wait, there is no way to turn off subtitles by default? What are the developers thinking? This is f'ing stupid.